# JDA RestAction Error - Max number of daily application command creates has been reached (200)

Tags: java, api, discord, bots

I am currently working on a Discord Bot. I use the JDA for that. When I tried starting the bot I got this error:

```
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR RestAction - RestAction queue returned failure: [ErrorResponseException] 30034: Max number of daily application command creates has been reached (200)
net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException.here(ContextException.java:54)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Request.<init>(Request.java:71)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.RestActionImpl.queue(RestActionImpl.java:197)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction.queue(RestAction.java:573)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction.queue(RestAction.java:539)
    at fab3F.Bot.main(Bot.java:88)
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO JDA - Finished Loading!
```

I never had this error before, but I have 16 Slash Commands for my bot. I dont know why I can only create 200 commands daily, that means I can start the bot 12 times. But I have to test the bot and I have to restart it more than 12 times a day.
I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Restarting the bot with the same commands should not cause you to hit the limit, if you did it properly. Without code, we have no way to tell.